# How can i get a column value join same table value

Tags: mysql

**users**

`user_types` 1 = admin 
 2= distributer 
 3= retailer

---

```
    user_id | user_name| user_type| user_under|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1      | user1    | 1        | 0      
     2      | user2    | 3        | 2  
     3      | user3    | 2        | 0
     4      | user4    | 3        | 2
     5      | user5    | 3        | 2
```

**recharge**

---

```
    rech_id | user_id| amount| 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1      | 2    | 249
     2      | 4    | 495
     3      | 5    | 175
```

**wanted result**

---

```
    rech_id | user_id| user_under| 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1      | 2    | user3           
     2      | 4    | user3
     3      | 5    | user3
```

i want to list all user distributer name by joining with recharge table

Comment: What did you tried? show us you code

Comment: Your question is not clear and your effort also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, in output table, you need only those user_id which are present in both users and recharge, so apply inner join.
Next,

1. rech_id can be fetched from recharge table
2. user_id can be fetched either from users or recharge table.
3. for user_type, there is a pattern in wanted_result i.e. a combination of "user" keyword with user_type of users table. so use concat("user",user_type)

```sql
select re.rech_id,re.user_id,concat("user",us.user_type) as user_under
    from users us inner join recharge re USING (user_id)
```

Comment: Assuming that your query does exactly what was asked (I cannot try), it would be nice for others if you would add some explainations to understand what is going on and why it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join for this result. I don't understand you question exaclty but you need to use code like this:

```
  select rech_id,user_id,user_under from users INNER JOIN recharge ON users.user_id=recharge.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make effort fixing your probleme, dont just ask in here.
anyway i think this can solve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN recharge AS r on r.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_name;
```

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY u.user_name` is 99% out off the cases invalid SQL.. This is not how you generally should use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) in SQL unless [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) could be used on the `u.user_name` column